# cmd script printing out but not executing

Tags: cmd, mediainfo

Hi all I'm currently writing up a small bash script to automate some stuff for me but I've hit a bit of a snag My current file looks like the following:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b "D:/*"') do C:\MediaInfo\MediaInfo.exe "--Inform=Video;%Width% "D:\%%f"
pause > nul
```

The pause thing is just there so I can see the output. While the part after the |do| command works fine if I manually type it in (as in I know my syntax for that is correct) however when running the batch script instead of actually executing the above commands it simply prints them out to the command console. Am I missing some syntax here or similar. Also as a side note I would like to push the resulting value of that query into an int so I can use it, do you know if this is possible in bash or should I look at trying to use a higher level language? Thanks!

Comment: You are writing a "bash script" - are you sure?

Comment: your working with Windows Shell script, not bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no notion of the intricacies of `mediainfo` - but it would be unusual if it was to accept unbalanced quotes in its command line as you have posted. I'd suggest an extra after `%Width%`